# Send index in my map function using java stream

Tags: java

I have a method that return me an `List<String[]>` like that:

```
return getElements()
                .stream()
                .map(Element::elements)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My elements function look like that:

```
public String[] elements ()
```

I want to send the index of the current iteration in my elements method so i try to give an index in my map like that and to put an index arguments in my elemnts method.

```
return getElements()
                .stream()
                .map(Element::elements, index)

public String[] elements (int index)
```

I have the following errors:

```
'map(java.util.function.Function? super ch........,? extends java.lang.String[]>)' in 'java.util.stream.Stream' cannot be applied to '( , int)'
```

I tried to use a filter and then use mapToObj but it don't recognize the mapToObj function.

I need to send the index because i need to do a specific check in me method if the index is equal to 3.

Is it a way to filter with the index or to send the index to my map method ?

I already tried AtomicInteger:

```
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);

        return getAllokationen()
                .stream()
                .map(Element::element, index.getAndIncrement())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Without sucesss

Thank you

Comment: .map(e -> e.elements[index])

Comment: The creation of a list of data-pairs `<array-index, array-value>` from an array is not naively stateless. Thus, I would recommend not doing this mapping in a streamified manner and instead implementing it imperatively.

Comment: What *exactly* do you expect to happen at `.map(Element::elements, index)`? Could you provide example of some *initial* data and result you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A concise solution will be to use `IntStream`. Your question is a bit vague on the input parameters to the `elements()` function, never the less, I've assumed that `getElements()` returns a `List<Elements>` and you require the index of that list to perform the operation.

```
List<Elements> elementList = getElements();
IntStream.range(0, elementList.size())
         .mapToObj(index -> elementList.get(index).elements(index))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Hope this works out for you.